# Embedded System State Pattern: Storing information related to asynchronous events

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns, embedded

I have a embedded system software, where I go through bunch of hardware initialization steps and then go to either Mode1 or Mode2 depending on history of events that occurred. Even within a certain mode, I do certain things depending on the history of events

e.g. 
if my display is off then in Mode 1 I take a flow which is different than what I would taken if the display was on. And the display notification arrives asynchronously, I don't explicitly query for that information.

There are few other similar events that arrive asynchronously that can change the course of action I would take further down the flow.

I am trying to understand how to store the information related to these events that happened in the past. I am inclined to store them as flags but then it defeats the purpose of using state pattern (and it is also error prone).

Another option I have is store these information in the state itself e.g.
Mode1_DisplayOff_Atrribx, Mode1_DisplayOff_Atrribx, Mode2_DisplayOff_Atrribx, Mode2_DisplayOff_Atrriby. But I fear this will make the state machine complex.

What should be the right approach here?

(Question is not necessarily related to embedded systems)

Comment: I'd say go with the sub-state approach, modelling each option as a state (second alternative you gave). If it seems complex, that means that your logic is indeed complex and hiding that with a lot of flags won't make it any less so, only cause more issues down the road.

Comment: This is a question for Programmers.SE.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nah that site closes everything as off-topic, because nobody knows what's on topic there, including the mods...

Comment: @Lundin: Except I confirmed with them that it is on-topic there, before posting my comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Any question at that site might get closed for completely arbitrary reasons, no matter with what some people on their meta might say. It may be that the question is on topic there (today/depending on mood/location of the planets) but I still wouldn't recommend anyone to use that site. The question is on-topic here, so there is no reason to move it anyhow.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange. Next time I will keep this in mind while posting the question.

Comment: @Lundin: Doesn't look on-topic here to me. Questions such as this are the reason for Programmers.SE's existence. And I don't see what "their meta" has to do with it; I was talking with three site moderators and two high-profile contributors. Is their opinion for some reason unsatisfactory to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general design advise for this case, or for any case with complex state handling:

- Overall design advise: keep it as simple as possible. Strive for simplicity, not complexity.
- Create a state machine corresponding to the number of combinations of "modes", "events", "flags" etc that you have. This can be as simple or as advanced as needed - sometimes you might need to implement sub-states (for example in state "error", there are sub states "error display" and "error adc" etc).
- Avoid a jungle of flags: it is bad enough that you have to collect flags from numerous sources. If you also combine this with local decision makers, you will have to write complex code all over your program, where the local decision makers cause state changes. It will very soon turn impossible to keep track of program flow and code coverage.

  This also tends to lead to tight coupling between a lot of modules that could have been independent of each other, which is always a very bad thing.
- Implement a standardized error handler for all states, with a standard error data type (error number, error origin etc).
- Keep the asynchronous information gathering separate from the state machine. That is, if the asynchronous events happen independently of which state the program is currently executing. If they don't, you'll have to integrate them in the state machine.
- Centralize the decision making of what to do next, at one single place in the program. Preferably combined with the error handler.

Your main loop would then look something like:

```
for(;;)
{
  state_result = state_machine[current_state]();
  event_result = gather_event(); // might need several of these

  current_state = evaluate_results (state_result, event_result);
}
```

Where `evaluate_results` is the *only* place in your program where state changes are allowed to occur. This function is only concerned with what state to execute next, it does not perform any actual work.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer. It's very helpful Thanks!! In my case the asynchronous events play an important role in decision making part of state machine. Currently I am going with the advice of not having flags and have the information embedded in the state machine. Thanks again for your help..

Comment: @patronus can you please share what was your final outcome?